# Search Query on Multiple Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-search

Hello I am trying to implement the search functionality on multiple fragment but I only got it to work on only one Fragment. What I did?
On each of my fragment, I have this Line of code

```
 public void bindData(String strSearchText) {
   // This method its array from Resources. and its different from fragment to fragment 
   Object[] arrayItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.BikeList);
   if (strSearchText != null && strSearchText.length() > 0) {
    List<Object> lstFilteredItems = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Object item : arrayItems) {
        if (((String)item).contains(strSearchText)) {
            lstFilteredItems.add(item);
        }
    }
    arrayItems = lstFilteredItems.toArray();
}
ArrayAdapter<Object> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(),R.layout.fragment_sub_list,R.id.topText,arrayItems);    
setListAdapter(adapter);
getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
}
```

On my main Activity, I have this piece of code.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.home_page, menu);
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager)getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(
            new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), SearchResultActivity.class)));
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String strSearchText) {
    //how do i switch between them? based on whatever fragment the user is
    bikeSublist.bindData(strSearchText); //bikefragment  
    //carSublist.bindData(strSearchText);//carfragment

    return true;
}
```

I can only use one at a time. And the user must be ( for this case now) on the bike fragment. But I want a situation that, no matter what fragment the user is on, it can be able to get the search query from different fragment. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

How about making a interface that is implemented in each of your fragment .

```
public interface SearchData {
    void bindData(String strSearchText);
}
```

Then in your`onQueryTextChange(String strSearchText)` method you check if the current shown fragment and use that method if that's the case .

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String strSearchText) {
    Fragment currentFragment = getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
    if (currentFragment  instanceof SearchData )
    {
        currentFragment.bindData(strSearchText);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for bothering you. Do I write the first piece of code on my main Activity? or on each fragment? Please I am still growing in software programing and new to Java and Android. Help.

Answer (score 0):

Gather all the resources like `getResources().getStringArray(R.array.BikeList);` at common place and use for search. As the elements you want to be search are from 'Resources' then you can gather it at a common access location.

For example:

use `static` List< E > holding all the `resources`

Comment: Please can you help me on how to do that. I tried something but It doesnt work on multiple fragment. The user has to be on a fragment I used at onQueryTextChange. For the case I posted, I was able to gather all the resources at a place, but my App would crash if the user searches from a fragment outside bikeSublist.bindData(strSearchText); //bikefragment.